# append on useFieldArray

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I would like to create an array of inputs with at least 1 input by default. while submitting the form inputs should not be empty.
returned data should be an array with the all the values of inputs

i've created this, and it works great but for some reason, append will not let me add/append new inputs while the previous one is empty.

https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-moon-fhh27j?file=/src/App.js

it will let you add extra input, only once the previous one is fulfilled with a value , and that's not the behaviour i want.
i would like to be able to add as many as you like in first place.

i can't explain why this is happening

any idea of how to workaround this issue? am i approaching this thing incorrectly?

```
  import "./styles.css";
    import { useFieldArray, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
    
    export default function App() {
      const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        formState: { errors },
        control
      } = useForm();
    
      const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
        control,
        name: "values"
      });
    
      const answerQuestion = (formData) => {
        console.log(formData);
        return;
      };
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>array of inputs</h1>
          <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(answerQuestion)} noValidate>
            <div className="form-body">
              {fields.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                  <div key={item.id}>
                    <input
                      {...register(`values.${index}`, {
                        required: "This field is required"
                      })}
                      type="text"
                    />
                    {index !== 0 && (
                      <button type="button" onClick={() => remove(index)}>
                        delete
                      </button>
                    )}
                    {errors.values && (
                      <span className="error">{errors.values[index]?.message}</span>
                    )}
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
    
            <button
              onClick={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                append("");
              }}
            >
              add field
            </button>
            <button className="edit">send data</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're register the input field, you're essentially also giving it a name. In this case its names "values". The reason the append is not working, is because it's not provided what to append. You have to provide it the name of the input field.

This is your register:  {...register(`values.${index}`, {
required: "This field is required"
})}
So this should be your append: append({ values: "" });

codesand box: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-https-4j281f?file=/src/App.js:1343-1365